# Is unequal application of a site TOS either a civil or criminal violation?

Tags: terms-of-service, discrimination

If a site is not treating all of its users the same way, and is applying the TOS against some users, but not others, is this in any way a violation of civil or criminal law?

Comment: Which jurisdiction?

Comment: I'm in NY, but not in NYC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the face of it: neither.

A party to a contract can choose not to enforce a term, this is called a waiver. They can choose to do this on a case by case basis either within the same contract or between contracts, that is, they can discriminate between customers.

Discrimination is only illegal if it is done on an illegal basis (e.g. race, sex, etc.).

Also woth noting, in general, there is no obligation on a private entity to act with fairness, unless the unfairness is so bad it is unconscionable.

Comment: That is certainly the case in England and Wales.  I can imagine it might vary by jurisdiction though.  Certainly protected characteristics vary by jurisdiction:  Until recently, discrimination on the basis of religion was legal in E&W, but illegal in Northern Ireland.

Comment: It is likely that international websites will need to have different TOS in order to operate in compliance with differing laws of differing jurisdictions. In addition, if different users subscribed to different types or levels of service then it can be appropriate to tailor the TOS as required, otherwise if a standard TOS is used for all users covering a whole number of services this could be so long it never gets read.